# Timestamps difference

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains two timestamps as in start and end as below I cant find the difference of these two but what I want is the difference between start of second row and end of first row.
My data is

```
time_df <- data.frame(start=as.POSIXct(c('2020-08-23 07:40:59','2020-08-23 08:22:28','2020-08-23 08:54:46','2020-08-23 09:23:17','2020-08-24 07:39:10','2020-08-24 08:13:06','2020-09-01 10:21:04','2020-09-02 06:14:54','2020-09-02 07:44:59'))
,end=as.POSIXct(c('2020-08-23 08:15:23','2020-08-23 08:46:41','2020-08-23 09:17:05','2020-08-23 09:51:20','2020-08-24 08:09:29','2020-08-24 08:37:45','2020-09-01 10:56:41','2020-09-02 06:43:02','2020-09-02 08:08:50')))
```

What I am trying

```
time_df$duration <- as.numeric(difftime(time_df$end,time_df$start,units ="mins"))
```

but I want to find the difference between start of second row and end of first row keeping above data frame in min I want the difference of (8:22:28 - 8:15:23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the 1st value from `start` and last value from `end` so that you can get difference of 2nd value of `start` and 1st value of `end`, 3rd value of `start` and 2nd value of `end` and so on. We append a `NA` value at the beginning to make the length equal to number of rows.

```
time_df$diff <- c(NA, difftime(time_df$start[-1], 
                               time_df$end[-nrow(time_df)], units = 'mins'))
```

Or if you use `dplyr`, you can use `lag` to get previous value :

```
library(dplyr)
time_df %>% mutate(diff = difftime(start, lag(end), units = 'mins'))

#                start                 end         diff
#1 2020-08-23 07:40:59 2020-08-23 08:15:23      NA mins
#2 2020-08-23 08:22:28 2020-08-23 08:46:41     7.1 mins
#3 2020-08-23 08:54:46 2020-08-23 09:17:05     8.1 mins
#4 2020-08-23 09:23:17 2020-08-23 09:51:20     6.2 mins
#5 2020-08-24 07:39:10 2020-08-24 08:09:29  1307.8 mins
#6 2020-08-24 08:13:06 2020-08-24 08:37:45     3.6 mins
#7 2020-09-01 10:21:04 2020-09-01 10:56:41 11623.3 mins
#8 2020-09-02 06:14:54 2020-09-02 06:43:02  1158.2 mins
#9 2020-09-02 07:44:59 2020-09-02 08:08:50    62.0 mins
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rowSums`. Convert `end` `as.numeric` to get the negative sign.

```
d <- rowSums(cbind(-as.numeric(time_df$end[-nrow(time_df)]), time_df$start[-1]))

d  ## seconds
# [1]    425    485    372  78470    217 697399  69493   3717

d/60  ## minutes
# [1]     7.083333     8.083333     6.200000  1307.833333
# [5]     3.616667 11623.316667  1158.216667    61.950000
```